# Cannot run uMongo on Ubuntu 14

Tags: mongodb

I've downloaded uMongo to my Ubuntu 14 OS.

I've extracted the zip to a directory.

When I double click it, I just get a text editor opened.

When I try to open it from terminal, nothing is happening:

```
username:~/Software/umongo-linux-all_1-6-2$ chmod +x launch-umongo.sh
username:~/Software/umongo-linux-all_1-6-2$
```

Any help will be profoundly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing

```
username:~/Software/umongo-linux-all_1-6-2$ chmod +x launch-umongo.sh
```

would only set the permissions of `launch-umongo.sh` to execute and not launch it.

To launch it from the terminal, type `./launch-umongo.sh` after doing the `chmod +x` command from earlier. Since you have set it to have execute permissions, you can run the script from the file manager by double-clicking it.

The reason why you get a text editor when you run it is because the file only has read/write permissions from the start when you extracted it.

Comment: In addition, once it is executable, when you double click in teh GUI it may prompt you to open/run it or to view it (open in a text editor)

Comment: @ivanivan I guess that would differ depending on the desktop environment used, right?

Comment: Probably, but I've noticed it in KDE, MATE, and Gnome 2x ...